# How to add a new page to Mezzanine project

Tags: django, django-cms, mezzanine

I am using Mezzanine - CMS in Django and I want to create a page for user account. The link for the page needs to be added to the top bar navigation. The user account page does not have a lot of functionality and is somewhat similar to About page.

I have been trying to look around, but have not really been able to figure out how to add the urls and templates for a new page. Can anyone please point me the right direction, so that I can get started.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to add this page to the actual site, or to the admin area?

Comment: On the actual site, not the admin

Comment: are you familiar with Django outside of Mezzanine? how do you want to interact with the page? would this be info on the current user / list of all users / ... -- could create a mezzanine content plugin that would display basic user information -- create a standard view outside of mezzanine -- etc...

Comment: @Alvin: The main issue was that I wanted to the name of the page in the top navigation bar, but now I know how to do that. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to the question in context from comments to allow marking the question answered.

Username in template -- standard Django so long as you are using request in your template Context

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

view:

```
render(request, template, context)
```

template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a bit of an issue with this and kept on coming across this question without real answers. This answer would have saved me a few hours.

So in 2017 the answer is to read the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/). Just looking through the Mezzanine docs is hopeless as they assume that you know Django decently before using their stuff.

You can do things like add the pages already included in Mezzanine like Link, Richtext, etc (i.e. those listed in their docs [here](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html)) by doing the same as with any model by loading the django settings and making a new model instance by doing something like:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from mezzanine.pages.models import Link
>>> pageLink = Link()
>>> pageLink.set_slug("/PageName")
>>> pageLink.title("Page Name")
>>> pageLink.save()
```

All this does is load the django project by calling manage.py shell, then making an instance of the model is the API for the database behind it. Calling save commits the changes and they are ready to be migrated.

```
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```